# Hello, looking how to create the bottom curve to the corners of a hero image

Tags: image, svg, shapes

I am new to coding but learning steadily. I found a design I liked and noticed it was using SVG viewbox and a path. I just wonder how to replicate this type of shape for a hero image at the bottom. Please see attached screenshot.

Thank you.[Hero Image Landing Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sQns.jpg)

Comment: Please take a look at this pen: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/e141a3b023426d1b3a50a86a82c18be2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author has not provided any code and links to an off-site resource